# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::x()

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm getting the error, but I can't find why?

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::domains()

The error appears in this two lines of my controller:

```
$tags = Domains::query()->findOrFail($id);
$tags->domains()->attach($all_tags);
```

I'm using a pivot table, that's my `belongsToMany()` relation:

```
public function domains() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\technical\Domains', 'domain_tag', 'id', 'domains_id'); }
```

Does anyone see why?

Comment: You are calling model `Domain` and looking for it's `domains()`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you took wrong class:

```
$tags = Domains::query()->findOrFail($id);
```

I'm guessing that You want to take:

```
$tags = Tag::query()->findOrFail($id);
```

Or something like this